# Overlapping contour labels?

Tags: matlab, contour

So I'm trying to do contour plotting with each contour representing an increment of 0.1 on a correlation map.

```
[c2,h2] = contourm(GlobalCorrs,geoidrefvec, .2:.1:1,'k','LineWidth',1);
ht2 = clabelm(c2,h2);
```

The issue is.. when there are multiple closely-spaced contours, they tend to overlap, as shown in the top picture below.

[image]

But if I zoom into the bottom picture here, I can see that the 0.4 label was covered by up the 0.2 and 0.3 labels. This is problematic since a correlation of 0.4 is a lot more significant than a correlation of 0.2.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this so that either (1) higher correlation labels can cover up lower correlation labels, or (2) where I can get the correlation labels to be more randomly spaced around the figures?

Comment: I don't really know if this would work, but you could try playing around with setting the `LabelSpacing` argument of `clabelm`. It might change the position of the labels slightly around the contour lines.

Comment: Good idea. I just tried that but it still doesn't seem to work (probably since there is only one label per contour interval).

Comment: (also just tried a smaller value of labelspacing; the additional 0.2 labels still cover up the additional 0.4 labels).

Answer (score 2):

The `LabelSpacing` property doesn't offer you enough flexibility. It could help in some lucky cases. I'd recommend: just set the labels manually:

```
clabel(C,h,'manual',...)
```

giving you a cross hair to define where to set the labels.

[image]