# Avoid overlapping of contour line labels

Tags: matlab, plot, contour, contourf

I have a code like this

```
[Cp hp] = contourf(log2(S_pr),log2(C_pr),ClassRateMatr_pr);

clabel(Cp,hp,'LabelSpacing',150,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'fontsize',16);
```

Which gives me this
[image]

As you can see the labels overlap such a way that it's impossible to read,

How can I randomly place them or use other trick?

Thanks,

Comment: Related post: [Overlapping contour labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20110780/8239061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no convenient way to do what you want.

If you can't manage to get the desired result using `'LabelSpacing'`, there is probably no other easy way to achieve properly set labels automatically and reliable.

I'd recommend to do it manually:

```
[C,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,obj_Z);
t = clabel(C,h,'manual','LabelSpacing',2000,'FontSize',8)
```

when now the figure window pops up, a crosshair appears and you can click on every single contour line to exactly specify where to place the label. With some practice you get it done quite fast.
I hope you don't have a hundreds of plots like this ;)
Just prepare everything before you print your final plot and set it to `'manual'` as a last step.

Comment: It's what I've been looking for, thanks, Actually I have only 2 plots but I needed them to be clean!